# How do I return the dataframe from a function in Python?

Tags: python, function, dataframe

So here is my code:

```
    def assign(x):
        x=dataDct['{}'.format(x)]
        x=x[x['_id'].str.contains("784561B7F90F")]
        return(x)
```

x is my dataframe name.I pass it to dataDct , which is a dictionary, as a key. This returns me the dataframe when i don't use this function and just type the dataframe name manually. This dictionary is not declared inside the function. I dont know if that is causing a problem. I'm unable to declare the dictionary as global. In the second line I query a certain column of x. And in the end i should get dataFrame x.

So this is my original code:

```
    motions=dataDct['motions']
    motions=motions[motions['_id'].str.contains("784561B7F90F")]
    motions
```

motions is the name of the dataframe. The dataframe is already stored in the dictionary with the name as key. I just assigned it to a variable with same name. Since i have to access 33 files like motions and i was doing it manually, I decided to write the function instead. But its not working and im getting a key error.

Comment: are you trying to write a function that converts a dictionary into a dataframe? Can you add what is the content of x when call the function `ass`? btw cool naming

Comment: hey! haha thanks, although the naming was an accident. I edited my question with added information.

Comment: You mean that you have a dictionary which one of the fields is a dataframe?

Comment: yes, so i have a dictionary outside of this function. The dictionary key is my dataframe name and values are my columns. So dataDct['motions'] returns the dataframe. dataDct['motions][['_values_']] returns a single column in motions called values. I dont need pd.DataFrame as the dataDct['dataframename'] returns me the dataframe.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the error, the code seems to work. How do you call the function?

Comment: I call the function using assign(nameofdataframe). So for example:. assign(motions)